# Favicon binary data not converting into image

Tags: php, laravel, gd, imagick, yodlee

Favicon binary data not converting into image.

In my response I am getting byte array as follows:

```
 $byte_array = $response['defaultFavIcon'];
```

`$byte_array` contains image array as follows:

```
[ 0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 1
3 => 0
4 => 1
5 => 0
6 => 16
7 => 16
8 => 0
9 => 0
10 => 1
14 => 104
15 => 3
16 => 0
17 => 0
18 => 22
19 => 0
20 => 0
21 => 0
22 => 40
27 => 0
28 => 0
29 => 0
30 => 32
31 => 0
32 => 0
33 => 0
34 => 1
35 => 0
36 => 24
37 => 0
44 => 0 ..... so on]
```

By using above byte array I am doing as follows:

```
$data = implode('', array_map(function ($e) {
    return pack("C*", $e);
}, $byte_array));
```

By using image intervention package I am doing as follows:

```
$img = Image::make($data)->save(storage_path() . '/images/image1.jpg'); 
return $img->response();
```

By doing so I am not getting image for favicons, but I am getting images for siteLogos.

Note: mimeTypes are different for site logos and favicons
for siteLogos: `mime type` is `image/png`
for favicon: `mime type` is `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`

For siteLogos I am getting image as response. but i am not getting image for favicon.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it has something to do with the file format. Instead of saving as jpg, you should save as .ico

Comment: I have done with .ico also, but no result . I got same error in all cases those are saving file with .jpg, .png, .ico

Comment: Converting favicon's binary data to image should work, the same way it works for logos. There is no specific action required for favicons.